# Expect array contains object of type in typescript (Jest)

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I would like to code a unit test in typescript with Jest, that checks whether a returned array contains one element with a specified type. I am aware of the following methods:

1. `expect(array).toBeInstanceOf(myType)`: this does not work, since it only works for single elements and I want to check whether one element in the array has that type
2. `expect(array).toContain(myType)`: this does not work, since it checks for equality of the object I am passing in (I only care about the type)

Is there anyway in which I could combine the two? Or what would be the best way of doing this check?

Thanks,

Comment: Could you do `expect(array.some((element) => checkIfElementIsMyType(element))).toBe(true)`?